# Can we configure NSwagCSharp code generator in visualstudio csproj project file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, nswagstudio

NSwagStudio provide us with lots of settings to get a custom auto-generated swagger client in C#.

But when we use VisualStudio 2019 Solution Explorer and open the "Connected Services" on a project, we can add an OpenAPI service from a swagger json file, but I don't see any way to configure the code generator. So that you have a default one.

Is it possible to configure NSwagCSharp code generator in visualstudio csproj project file for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just fill in the '*Additional code generation options*' of the wizard using the "NSwag Command Line" syntax, i.e. :
/generateDtoTypes:false /injectHttpClient:true

Refer to the list of possible options on https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwag-Configuration-Document under section "openApiToCSharpClient".

This is also explained well on the blog:
https://stevetalkscode.co.uk/openapireference-commands

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Connected Service with [Unchase OpenAPI (Swagger) Connected Service](https://github.com/unchase/Unchase.OpenAPI.Connectedservice/) extension. It gives you the same options as you have seen in the NSwagStudio.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).